# Share ppt with VBA code

Tags: vba, share, powerpoint

I save my working PowerPoint presentation with some working VBA code and send it to a friend.

When my friend opens it the same functions that I wrote with VBA does not work.

How do I export the PowerPoint including the VBA code?

Thanks.

Comment: save as power point macro-enabled presentation

Comment: Define "Does not work". Does your friend get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: No error messages when my friend opens the PowerPoint.
I already tried to save it as PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file as .pptm (PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Presentation).
Make sure your friend allow the security settings to run the macro.

Comment: "Make sure your friend allow the security settings to run the macro."

I will try to look at this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is WRONG ->> (Are you sure that your code is actually attached to the presentation and it isn't in your PERSONAL workbook? You can either export the PERSONAL workbook to your friend or make it so the code is actually attached to the presentation. Probably easier to make the code be actually on the presentation and not your PERSONAL workbook. Also like other people said make sure it is macro enabled ppt and that macros are enabled if it doesn't work after that.)

(Apparently this isn't a thing. NEVERMIND.)

Comment: I don't think Powerpoint has a 'Personal Presentation' file.  Excel has the workbook, but not Powerpoint.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That's correct, PPT has nothing like this. Or even workbooks of any sort.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Always like to add _think_... whenever I don't someone comes along and proves me wrong. :)

Comment: Oh ok I just figured that it did and that may have been the issue. Thanks for the heads up. I edited my answer.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  Imagine that!  I have the same-shaped lumps on MY head too.